# Only part of border changes the color

Tags: html, css, border

I want to change the color only of 1/3 of the bottom border and i want it to be changed only when someone clicks on the text (summer, spring or winter). Is it possible to do something like this with only CSS (with pseudo-elements like before or after) or do i have to use JS in this case?

HTML:

```
<div class="seasons">
        <span id="text1">Summer</span>
        <span id="text2">Spring</span>
        <span id="text3">Winter</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.seasons {
    color: #B5BAB8;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #B5BAB8;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    margin-top: 465px;
  }

  .seasons span { 
    width: 250px;
    display: inline-block;
  }
```

Comment: It can be done without JS, but you would need a different HTML structure. What do you need the id's for that are defined for the spans?

Comment: For the clicking part. I think you need to use JS. If you really desire a pure css/html with the clicking part then you may have to you some un-orthodox solution that might be a bit complex where you use a checkbox with css styling to mimic click. If you want that then i can help with that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/9v1x3h2c/2/) could work using JS

**CSS**

```
.seasons {
    color: #B5BAB8;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 10px;
    margin-top: 465px;
}

.seasons span { 
    width: 250px;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #B5BAB8;
}

.seasons span.highlighted { 
    border-bottom-color: red;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.seasons span').on('click', function() {
    $('.seasons span').removeClass('highlighted');
    $(this).addClass('highlighted');
})
```

Comment: You just shared an empty jsfiddle link. What in the world?

Comment: @j08691- in the original question there is one border across the 'seasons' div. In my fiddle it it is selecting a third of that overall width.

Comment: @petlet - please can you clarify if this is what you're looking for

Comment: @RobHowells yes, this is exactly what i am looking for, thanks! i only need to 'translate' jQuery to pure JavaScript now

Comment: @j08691 - please see above

Comment: @petlet - here's one way you could approach it using vanilla js https://jsfiddle.net/udfdynbm/1/

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** upps. I guess you want to change just 33% percentage of the full border. I thought you want to change 33% percentage of the each span elements border. Which has almost the same width the texts.

I tried your code on Codepen but, before suggestions, let me answer your question first:

### Answer:

Yes you can -kinda- achive this without JS.

You have to use these following:

**1. Linear gradient borders:**
You can use

```
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 100%);
```

for your borders. That percentages may change as you like.

**2. :active, :focus or :hover pseudo states for these spans:**
You can change that gradient for click (:active) state.

```
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,0,0,0) 30%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 70%);
```

**3. Adding effects:**
You can also use

```
transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
```

for your effect.

### But my suggestion:

Using :after element with `position: absolute` for :active state.

You can create an :after element for these spans' :active states like this:

```
span:active:after{
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 1px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 5px;
    display: block;
}
```

You can add background to this pseudo element or you can also add normal border for this element.

If positioning not works, try `position: relative` for parents. This also requires `display: block` for spans.

Comment: thanks! i just changed the width from 100% to 33.33% and only the 1/3 of the border changes the color :)

Comment: but i guess i can't force this part of border (with different colour) to stay in the changed colour till someone clicks other text with only CSS, right? because something like transition: border-bottom 5s ease-in-out on the active state with before pseudoelement won't work? at least it doesn't work in my case, as i checked.

Comment: :active state is not like clicked event I assume; so you might right. Bu I've seen another answer up here, which uses "radio" buttons and checks their "checked" states with CSS, I liked that way of thinking. Try that also.

Answer (score 0):

Here a possibility without JS.

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

label {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #0ff;
}

label:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+label {
  border-bottom: 3px solid transparent;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to right, #f0f 0%, #f0f 33%, #3acfd5 33%, #fff, #3acfd5 34%, #0ff, 34%, #0ff 100%);
  border-image-slice: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="seasons">
  <form>
    <input id="summer" name="season" type="radio" value="summer">
    <label for="summer">Summer</label>
    <input id="spring" name="season" type="radio" value="spring">
    <label for="spring">Spring</label>
    <input id="winter" name="season" type="radio" value="winter">
    <label for="winter">Winter</label>
  </form>
</div>
```